# Trying to find apt java code logic for missing key in property file

Tags: java

I have a property file like this:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

This property file is using enum and while loop iteration to read next element.

In parallel to this, I have a string variable within for loop whose value changes for every iteration!

```
consider for first iteration,
string=key1
2nd iteration,
string=key2
3rd iteration,
string=key4
4th iteration,
string=key3
5th iteration,
string=key5.
```

As `key4` and `key5` is not present in property file, I want to display out "key4" and "key5"

The problem is I tried using `if(!string.equals(key))` within while using enum variable to reach to next element but I am stuck with repetitive results along with that using hash set to eliminate duplicates got me confused with the approach to logic am trying with.

A snippet of code is here

```
for (int i=0; i<bc.length; i++)
    {              
        Policy p[] = bc[i].getPolicies().getValue();
        String testcases = bc[i].getSearchPath().getValue(); 
        Enumeration<?> e1 = prop.propertyNames();
        while (e1.hasMoreElements())
        {
          key = (String) e1.nextElement();
          if(testcases.equals(key))
          { 
            System.out.println("match");
          } else
          {
            System.out.println("unmatched");
            set.add(testcases);//to eliminate duplicates
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You used `Properties` I guess, you didn't said. But [`Properties.getProperties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) return null if not found, you can get an enumeration with [`Properties.propertyNames`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames--) that you can iterate yourself.

Comment: As @GhostCat suggested i have added code snippet on the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
while (e1.hasMoreElements()) {
  key = (String) e1.nextElement();
  if (testcases.equals(key)) {
    ... IN ...
  } else {
    ... OUT ...
```

This logic is simply flawed. Basically you have that array from which you retrieve your test cases, like:

```
bc[i].getSearchPath().getValue();
```

And then you have your Properties, containing a list of properties. Your code does:

- iterate **all** "test cases"
- iterate **all** given properties

And each time a property key matches a test case you say "IN". And "OUT" for **all** other cases. That gives you way too many **false** outputs for "OUT".

Go for this instead:

```
for (int i=0; i<bc.length; i++) {
  String matchingKey = null;
  while (e1.hasMoreElements()) {
    key = (String) e1.nextElement();
    if (testcases.equals(key)) {
      matchingKey = key;
      break;
    }
  } 
  if (matchingKey != null) {
    ... IN ...

  } else {   
   ... OUT ...
```

And thanks to the comment: if no other processing is required, you can save a few loop iterations and *break* from that inner loop.

Beyond that, if you really have **many** test cases to check for - it might be worthwhile to process the property names **once** and push them into a HashSet for example. To then simply use `set.contains()` later on.

Comment: Note that we don't have to iterate anymore if we found a value, so we could break the while loop.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense ... and gave some reason to further improve the answer.